# Open .Class file inside Jar and modified on it

Tags: java, jar, decompiler

I have a class file inside a jar I open with winzip but when I try to open it with sublime text it gave  me something like this

> 0800 5c07 005d 0800 5e08 005f 0800 6008
>   0061 0800 6208 0063 0800 6408 0065 0800
>   6608 0067 0800 6808 0069 0800 6a08 006b ...

I already use jd-gui but i am not able to modify it. Also I decompile file to read it but when I try to replace the old one it give me an error I guess I need to compile it again but don't know how to proceed.

Comment: "when I try to replace the old one it give me an error" ...  What gave you what  error?

Answer (score 1):

Class files are **always** read-only.
You can only copy those and modify it accordingly with your IDE as a separate Java file.

Comment: I use jd-gui and save the source now i have a .jar.src.zip  file. now i need to change it to .jar

Answer (score 1):

You already said it yourself, you have to compile your code again, in a .class file all code is already compiled and therefore obfuscated.
Modifiable code will normally use .java file extensions, these are non compiled source code files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to execute jar again Inorder to extract code.

```
java -jar test.jar
```

for more User-interface look at [this](http://windowstipoftheday.blogspot.com/2005/10/setting-jar-file-association.html)